# Scrapy combine text along with the bold

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

With Scrapy, the following extract works ok just for normal text. It excludes all the BOLD tags that I am  trying to retrive:

```
hxs.select('//td[@class="Info_Cell"]/text()').extract()
```

The following just extracts the BOLD text, but excludes normal text.

```
hxs.select('//td[@class="Info_Cell"]/b/text()').extract()
```

How would you extract Text, normal and with Bold tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general `//` will extract recursively all child nodes, so in your case you need:

```
hxs.select('//td[@class="Info_Cell"]//text()').extract()
```